# Accessing files selected by user through HTML5 File System API across several refreshes

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

Okay, so the user has selected multiple files through the file chooser dialog and using HTML5 File System API I display their names and sizes. After that's done, I refresh the same page, which is served by a servlet; and on refresh the servlet writes in some JavaScript that again uses the 'file' vars to access the last modified date. This doesn't seem to work.

I believe this is a session management issue maybe the HTML5 File API does not allow access across different session. Or is it only supposed to be used for javascript to be executed in a single go?? Please tell me how I can access the same file vars across several pages, if needed they can be set to the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use HTML5's [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage), which will be cleared at the end of the browser session.

Or, if you want a persistent storage then you need [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

All this is assuming that all of your pages are being served from the same domain, otherwise you will a problem with the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: It's for a project which is a java API for accessing client files over the web, I am using a simple jetty handler that firstly serves the file selection JS code and refreshes the page. All the time, the page keeps refreshing every 3 seconds and if any new script has to be sent, it is done through the same handler. Since the new script will also refer these selected file vars, I need a solution for this. Thank you..I'll check if your suggestion works and upvote it.